# Neo4j Restful VS Neo4j JDBC

Tags: neo4j

What are the comparative advantages of querying a neo4j DB via

- REST API
- JDBC
- as a Spring Data plugin

Comment: Consider using the [Neo4J Java driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver), which uses the new BOLT protocol

Answer (score 2):

Performance will be better within Java using JDBC as opposed to a REST API. [Here's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286788/what-is-faster-using-rest-api-or-querying-a-database-directly) a good explanation of why:

> When you add complexity the code will run slower. Introducing a REST
>   service if it's not required will slow the execution down as the
>   system is doing more.
>
> Abstracting the database is good practice. If you're worried about
>   speed you could look into caching the data in memory so that the
>   database doesn't need to be touched to handle the request.
>
> Before optimizing performance though I'd look into what problem you're
>   trying to solve and the architecture you're using, I'm struggling to
>   think of a situation where the database options would be direct access
>   vs REST.

Regarding using neo4j as a plugin you [can](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) certainly do so, but I have to imagine the performance would not be as good as using JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

From the book "Graph Databases" - Ian Robinson

> Queries run fastest when the portions of the graph needed to satisfy
>   them reside in main memory (that is, in the filesystem cache and the
>   object cache). A single graph database instance today can hold many
>   billions of nodes, relationships, and properties, meaning that some
>   graphs will be just too big to fit into main memory.

If you add another layer to the app, this will be reflected in performance, so the bare you can consumes your data the better the performance but also the complexity and understanding of the code.